# Как оптимизировать цикл FOR (PHP)

Tags: php, циклы, оптимизация, for

Хочу оптимизировать цикл, который выполняет функцию списание средств с карты клиента для этого нужно выполнить два запроса. На данный момент все работает, но боюсь что код сломается когда клиентов станет больше. В php я полный нуль, пожалуйста подскажите как я мог бы оптимизировать данный цикл, чтобы избежать нагрузки на сервер.
На данный момент возникают идеи с интервалами, но не знаю как их можно реализовать.

В count($set) лежат данные которые я получил из БД: id и RebillId.

```
for($i = 0, $size = count($set); $i < $size; ++$i) {
    
    $id = $set[$i]['id'];
    $RebillId = $set[$i]['RebillId'];
    $TerminalKey = "1652780585356";
    $Password = "dbcjaacyvnr5";
    $OrderId = $id. $time;
    $Description = "Основная оплата подписки";
    $Amount = "100000";
    
      $array = array(
    'TerminalKey' => $TerminalKey,
    'pass' => $pass,
    'Amount' => $Amount,
    'OrderId' => $OrderId,
    'Description' => $Description
    );

$array = json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$ch = curl_init('https://securepay.tinkoff.ru/v2/Init');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','charset=UTF-8'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$res = json_decode($res, true);
print_r($res);

$PaymentId = $res["PaymentId"];
$PaymentURL = $res["PaymentURL"];


$token = array(
    'Password' => "$Password",
    'PaymentId' => "$PaymentId",
    'RebillId' => "$RebillId",
    'TerminalKey' => "$TerminalKey"
    );

$token = $token["Password"]. $token["PaymentId"]. $token["RebillId"]. $token["TerminalKey"];    
$token = hash('sha256', $token);
$token = mb_strtolower($token);


$data = array(
    'TerminalKey' => $TerminalKey,
    'PaymentId' => $PaymentId,
    'RebillId' => $RebillId,
    'Token' => $token
    );
    
    $data = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$ch = curl_init('https://securepay.tinkoff.ru/v2/Charge');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','charset=UTF-8'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$res = json_decode($res, true);
print_r($res);

}
```

Comment: Расшифруйте что вы понимаете под словом оптимизация, на данный момент не понятно по какому критерию вы хотите "оптимизировать", по потреблению памяти? процессора? скорости исполнения? ....?

Comment: Память, что бы сервер не лег.

Comment: Тогда первое что приходит в голову - убрать вообще из кода создание переменной ```$set``` собирайте данные сразу в нужный формат чтоб небыло необходимости их перекладывать с места на место.
2) т.к. у вас много запросов _(count($set)*2)_, можно воспользоваться multi_curl 
3) Если вы хотите экономить память(что странно в нынешнем мире) - очищайте за собой как только переменная стала не нужна (unset) и старайтесь всюду где возможно использовать ссылки а не копии переменных.

Comment: У вас может быть проблема с памятью, только если $set станет большим. значит надо в него читать частями или вообще по одной строке читать и обрабатывать. Но интересно как вообще такой скрипт работает, что будет если например во время его выполнения перезагрузиться сервер или что то с каналом интернета или проблемы на стороне банка. Вы даже не проверяете ни на какие ошибки, что если curl ошибку вернет ?

Comment: И с точки зрения оптимизации может оказаться, что надо будет выполнять параллельно несколько таких скриптов каждый из которых будет выполнять работу по какой то части пользователей, потому что основные тормоза будут именно на curl запросах и при большом кол-ве клиентов/долгом времени ответа банка вы просто будете не успевать все провести в один поток